# jQuery Selector issue finding href with text category1 in it

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a set of hyperlinks with href = javascript:method('category1') and likewise category2 category3 ...

I want to select hyperlink with href containing category1 so i have written

jQuery(a[href*='category1']) but dont know why it also selects hyperlinks with category10 category11 category12 ... also

I understand that category1 is common in all of them but 'category1' should'nt be do i need to put ' with escape charaters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
jQuery("a[href=javascript:method('category1')]");
```

Just do `=` if you only want category1, and define the entire href.

Also, you're missing the outer quotation marks.

---

**EDIT:**

Alternatively, you could use the 'attribute ends with' selector if you want to shorten it up a bit.

```
jQuery("a[href$=('category1')]");
```

Comment: thanks patrick it worked, i for some reason could not have used an exact= so had to use * but refining it further helps thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

How about adding an id to each hyperlink to easier select them?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Attribute contains](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) selector.

```
$("a[href*=category]");
```